# Perform a coordinate transformation of a 4th-order tensor with np.einsum and np.tensordot

Tags: numpy, numpy-einsum

The equation is

```
$C'_{ijkl} = Q_{im} Q_{jn} C_{mnop} (Q^{-1})_{ok} (Q^{-1})_{pl}$
```

I was able to use

```
np.einsum('im,jn,mnop,ok,pl', Q, Q, C, Q_inv, Q_inv)
```

to do the job, and also expect

```
np.tensordot(np.tensordot(np.tensordot(Q, np.tensordot(Q, C, axes=[1,1]), axes=[1,0]), Q_inv, axes=[2,0]), Q_inv, axes=[3,0])
```

to work, but it doesn't.

Specifics:

C is a 4th-order elastic tensor:

```
array([[[[ 552.62389047,   -0.28689554,   -0.32194701],
         [  -0.28689554,  118.89168597,   -0.65559912],
         [  -0.32194701,   -0.65559912,  130.21758722]],

        [[  -0.28689554,  166.02923119,   -0.00000123],
         [ 166.02923119,    0.49494431,   -0.00000127],
         [  -0.00000123,   -0.00000127,   -0.57156702]],

        [[  -0.32194701,   -0.00000123,  165.99413061],
         [  -0.00000123,   -0.64666809,   -0.0000013 ],
         [ 165.99413061,   -0.0000013 ,    0.42997465]]],


       [[[  -0.28689554,  166.02923119,   -0.00000123],
         [ 166.02923119,    0.49494431,   -0.00000127],
         [  -0.00000123,   -0.00000127,   -0.57156702]],

        [[ 118.89168597,    0.49494431,   -0.64666809],
         [   0.49494431,  516.15898907,   -0.33132485],
         [  -0.64666809,   -0.33132485,  140.09010389]],

        [[  -0.65559912,   -0.00000127,   -0.0000013 ],
         [  -0.00000127,   -0.33132485,  165.98553869],
         [  -0.0000013 ,  165.98553869,    0.41913346]]],


       [[[  -0.32194701,   -0.00000123,  165.99413061],
         [  -0.00000123,   -0.64666809,   -0.0000013 ],
         [ 165.99413061,   -0.0000013 ,    0.42997465]],

        [[  -0.65559912,   -0.00000127,   -0.0000013 ],
         [  -0.00000127,   -0.33132485,  165.98553869],
         [  -0.0000013 ,  165.98553869,    0.41913346]],

        [[ 130.21758722,   -0.57156702,    0.42997465],
         [  -0.57156702,  140.09010389,    0.41913346],
         [   0.42997465,    0.41913346,  486.62412063]]]])
```

Q is a rotation matrix changing x and y coords.

```
array([[ 0,  1,  0],
       [-1,  0,  0],
       [ 0,  0,  1]])
```

Q_inv is

```
array([[-0., -1., -0.],
       [ 1.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  1.]])
```

`np.einsum` leads to

```
array([[[[ 516.15898907,   -0.49494431,   -0.33132485],
         [  -0.49494431,  118.89168597,    0.64666809],
         [  -0.33132485,    0.64666809,  140.09010389]],

        [[  -0.49494431,  166.02923119,    0.00000127],
         [ 166.02923119,    0.28689554,   -0.00000123],
         [   0.00000127,   -0.00000123,    0.57156702]],

        [[  -0.33132485,    0.00000127,  165.98553869],
         [   0.00000127,   -0.65559912,    0.0000013 ],
         [ 165.98553869,    0.0000013 ,    0.41913346]]],


       [[[  -0.49494431,  166.02923119,    0.00000127],
         [ 166.02923119,    0.28689554,   -0.00000123],
         [   0.00000127,   -0.00000123,    0.57156702]],

        [[ 118.89168597,    0.28689554,   -0.65559912],
         [   0.28689554,  552.62389047,    0.32194701],
         [  -0.65559912,    0.32194701,  130.21758722]],

        [[   0.64666809,   -0.00000123,    0.0000013 ],
         [  -0.00000123,    0.32194701,  165.99413061],
         [   0.0000013 ,  165.99413061,   -0.42997465]]],


       [[[  -0.33132485,    0.00000127,  165.98553869],
         [   0.00000127,   -0.65559912,    0.0000013 ],
         [ 165.98553869,    0.0000013 ,    0.41913346]],

        [[   0.64666809,   -0.00000123,    0.0000013 ],
         [  -0.00000123,    0.32194701,  165.99413061],
         [   0.0000013 ,  165.99413061,   -0.42997465]],

        [[ 140.09010389,    0.57156702,    0.41913346],
         [   0.57156702,  130.21758722,   -0.42997465],
         [   0.41913346,   -0.42997465,  486.62412063]]]])
```

which I believe is correct, while four `np.tensordot` leads to

```
array([[[[ 552.62389047,   -0.28689554,    0.32194701],
         [  -0.28689554,  118.89168597,    0.65559912],
         [  -0.32194701,   -0.65559912, -130.21758722]],

        [[  -0.28689554,  166.02923119,    0.00000123],
         [ 166.02923119,    0.49494431,    0.00000127],
         [  -0.00000123,   -0.00000127,    0.57156702]],

        [[  -0.32194701,   -0.00000123, -165.99413061],
         [  -0.00000123,   -0.64666809,    0.0000013 ],
         [ 165.99413061,   -0.0000013 ,   -0.42997465]]],


       [[[  -0.28689554,  166.02923119,    0.00000123],
         [ 166.02923119,    0.49494431,    0.00000127],
         [  -0.00000123,   -0.00000127,    0.57156702]],

        [[ 118.89168597,    0.49494431,    0.64666809],
         [   0.49494431,  516.15898907,    0.33132485],
         [  -0.64666809,   -0.33132485, -140.09010389]],

        [[  -0.65559912,   -0.00000127,    0.0000013 ],
         [  -0.00000127,   -0.33132485, -165.98553869],
         [  -0.0000013 ,  165.98553869,   -0.41913346]]],


       [[[   0.32194701,    0.00000123,  165.99413061],
         [   0.00000123,    0.64666809,   -0.0000013 ],
         [-165.99413061,    0.0000013 ,    0.42997465]],

        [[   0.65559912,    0.00000127,   -0.0000013 ],
         [   0.00000127,    0.33132485,  165.98553869],
         [   0.0000013 , -165.98553869,    0.41913346]],

        [[-130.21758722,    0.57156702,    0.42997465],
         [   0.57156702, -140.09010389,    0.41913346],
         [  -0.42997465,   -0.41913346,  486.62412063]]]])
```

Notice the negative big numbers.

Comment: Your question won't work either; it is incomplete.  Show us where/how `tensordot` does not work - errors and/or wrong answer (esp. shape).

Comment: Sorry about that. I thought there must have been some obvious mistakes in calling `np.tensordot` that is easy to be detected by just looking at it. It's updated with an example.

Comment: You (or someone) needs to debug this step by step.  In other words, make sure each `tensordot` matches the equivalent `einsum`.  It's hard to wrap my mind around 4 nested `tensordot` expressions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Approach #1**

One way would be to use [`np.tensordot`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.1/reference/generated/numpy.tensordot.html) to get the same result as with `np.einsum` though not in a single step and with some help from the *trusty* [`broadcasting`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.1/user/basics.broadcasting.html) -

```
# Get broadcasted elementwise multiplication between two versions of Q.
# This corresponds to "np.einsum('im,jn,..', Q, Q)" producing "'ijmn"" 
# broadcasted version of elementwise multiplications between Q's.
Q_ext = Q[:,None,:,None]*Q[:,None,:]

# Similarly for Q_inv : For "np.einsum('..ok,pl', Q_inv, Q_inv)" get "'opkl'" 
# broadcasted version of elementwise multiplications between Q_inv's.
Q_inv_ext = Q_inv[:,None,:,None]*Q_inv[:,None,:]

# Perform "np.einsum('im,jn,mnop,ok,pl', Q, Q, C)" with "np.tensordot".
# Notice that we are using the last two axes from 'Q_ext', so "axes=[2,3]"
# and first two from 'C', so "axes=[0,1]" for it. 
# These axes would be reduced by the dot-product, leaving us with 'ijop'.
parte1 = np.tensordot(Q_ext,C,axes=([2,3],[0,1]))

# Do it one more time to perform "np.einsum('ijop,ok,pl', parte1,Q_inv,Q_inv)"
# to reduce dimensions represented by 'o,p', leaving us with 'ijkl'.
# To confirm, compare the following against original einsum approach :
# "np.einsum('im,jn,mnop,ok,pl->ijkl', Q, Q, C, Q_inv, Q_inv)"
out = np.tensordot(parte1,Q_inv_ext,axes=([2,3],[0,1]))
```

**Approach #2**

If you wish to avoid `broadcasting` in favour of using two more instances of `np.tensordot`, you could do -

```
# Perform "np.einsum('jn,mnop', Q, C). Notice how, Q is represented by 'jn' 
# and C by 'mnop'. We need to reduce the 'm' dimension, i.e. reduce 'axes=1'
# from Q and `axes=1` from C corresponding to `n' in each of the inputs.
# Thus, 'jn' + 'mnop' => 'jmop' after 'n' is reduced and order is maintained.
Q_C1 = np.tensordot(Q,C,axes=([1],[1]))

# Perform "np.einsum('im,jn,mnop', Q, Q, C). We need to use Q and Q_C1.
# Q is 'im' and Q_C1 is 'jmop'. Thus, again we need to reduce 'axes=1'
# from Q and `axes=1` from Q_C1 corresponding to `m' in each of the inputs.
# Thus, 'im' + 'jmop' => 'ijop' after 'm' is reduced and order is maintained.
parte1 = np.tensordot(Q,Q_C1,axes=([1],[1]))

# Use the same philosophy to get the rest of the einsum equivalent, 
# but use parte1 and go right and use Q_inv 
out = np.tensordot(np.tensordot(parte1,Q_inv,axes=([2],[0])),Q_inv,axes=([2],[0]))
```

The trick with `np.tensordot` is to keep track of the dimensions that are reduced by the `axes` parameter and how the collapsed dimensions align against the remaining inputs' dimensions.

Comment: It works. Is `Q[:,None,:,None]*Q[:,None,:]` the same as `Q[:,None,:,None]*Q[None,:,None,:]` though?

Comment: I'm still quite curious as to why the four `tensordot` solution doesn't work. Could you illustrate that?

Comment: @terencezl That's right. Omitted the leading `None` for brevity, but you might want to keep it for a better understanding.

Comment: It does make sense. But doesn't `np.tensordot(Q, np.tensordot(Q, C, axes=[1,1]), axes=[1,0])` also do a two-step reduction for the first half: `np.einsum('im,jn,mnop', Q, Q, C)`? They give different results. I think it's where the problem and my confusion lie.

Comment: Looks like `np.tensordot(Q, np.tensordot(Q, C, axes=[1,0]), axes=[1,1])` is the right way. Notice the axes order. Why are they different?

Comment: @terencezl Hope the just added second approach would fulfill your needs :)

Comment: Thanks. If I can ask why the two axes arguments are the same in each half?

Comment: @terencezl As I said, each `tensordot` collapses and thus re-arranges dimensions. If you keep track of those, the numbers inside the `axes` would be such. The axes arguments just appear to be same, but that's just coincidental.

Comment: Then how is one able to know the general rule of the collapse and rearrange behavior? I cannot find a good analogy to help analyze or remember, and intuition tells me since Q_{im} A_{mn} leads to Q'_{in}, i replacing m at the same position, natually Q_{im} Q_{jn} C_{mnop} would need i replacing m (axes=[1,0]), j replacing n (axes=[1,1]).

Comment: @terencezl Added extensive comments alongside codes.

Comment: Got you. That's very unexpected I'd say... I thought `'jn' + 'mnop' => 'mjop'` but it's actually `'jn' + 'mnop' => 'jmop'`. Side note: by saying "We need to reduce the 'm' dimension" did you mean "We need to reduce the 'n' dimension" in the first comment blcok?

Comment: @terencezl Sorry yes that should be `We need to reduce the 'n' dimension` in that first comment block. Also it would be 'jn' + 'mnop' => 'jmop' as also stated in the post, with 'n' being reduced.